# sharepoint pre-requisits installation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Trting to install sharepoint 2010 on Windows Server R2 Standard.

When running the install pre-requisits I get:
[image]

if I restart it continues the install and produces the same result. Always an error on the IIS config saying that it needs to restart. I did it over 4 times.

The log contains the following:

```
2012-07-16 16:32:39 - Request for install time of Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role
2012-07-16 16:32:40 - Request for install time of Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role
2012-07-16 16:32:41 - Request for install time of Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role
2012-07-16 16:32:42 - Request for install time of Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role
2012-07-16 16:32:43 - Request for install time of Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role
2012-07-16 16:32:44 - Install process returned (0X3E9=1001)
2012-07-16 16:32:44 - [In HRESULT format] (0X800703E9=-2147023895)
2012-07-16 16:32:44 - Last return code (0X3E9=1001)
2012-07-16 16:32:44 - Error: A pending restart blocks the installation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run windows update and get all updates for your 2008 R2 server.

It's the first step before installing SharePoint 2010.